# How can I output PHP array values using a foreach loop?

Tags: php, html, for-loop, foreach

Is there an easy way to output the values from an array into the following HTML format:

```
<div class="col col-3">
   <a href="#">North London</a>
   <a href="#">North West London</a>
</div>

<div class="col col-3">
    <a href="#">North London</a>
    <a href="#">North West London</a>
</div>

<div class="col col-3">
    <a href="#">North London</a>
    <a href="#">North West London</a>
</div>

<div class="col col-3">
    <a href="#">North London</a>
    <a href="#">North West London</a>
</div>
```

This is my for each loop, pretty basic:

```
<?php foreach ($values as $v) { 
$location = $v->value;
?>
```

So insert $location where each location currently lives in the HTML.

Comment: Question is on the first line '_Is there an easy way to output the vakues from an array into the following html format:_' (granted i had to have a second look to notice)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How foreach actually works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works)

Answer (score 1):

With the array already created, outputting the HTML code is nothing special; it's just having a print statement within your for-loop. My only concern is that you show two values in your DIV tags; I assumed that the first variable is your location variable; but I do not see where you are getting your second value.
Two solutions with the same results but different syntax:
Solution 1:

```
<?php 
foreach ($values as $v) { 
  $location = $v->value;
  $location2 = $v->value2; //My assumption
?>
  <div class="col col-3">
     <a href="#"><?php echo $location; ?></a>
     <a href="#"><?php echo $location2; ?></a>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Solution 2:

```
<?php 
foreach ($values as $v) { 
  $location = $v->value;
  $location2 = $v->value2; //My assumption
  echo '<div class="col col-3"><a href="#">' . $location . '</a><a href="#">' . $location2 . '</a></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Your answer is good too, except the the echoing and quoting could be troublesome for some people.

Comment: Yeah good point; I should show an example of both thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php 
foreach ($values as $v) { 
$location = $v->value;
$second   = $v->value2;
?>
<div class="col col-3">
    <a href="#"><?php echo $location;?></a>
    <a href="#"><?php echo $second;?></a>
</div>
</php
}
?>
```

Comment: I think the alternative syntax makes sense in this case (`foreach:` / `endforeach`), and the `<?=` short tag

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple to achieve

```
foreach ($locationsArray as $l) { 
$location = $l->location1;
$location2 = $l->location2; 
//get the value however u have stored in your object or array
?>
 <div class="col col-3">
 <a href="#"><?php echo $location; ?></a>
 <a href="#"><?php echo $location2; ?></a>
 </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Did you read either of the other solutions (both submitted 45 minutes ago) before you decided to post? Also I assume by this point that the OP has already left SO and is not going to accept anyone's answer.